# Attempting to launch an unregistered ActivityResultLauncher

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult

Sometimes I'm getting this IllegalStateException, and it says that you must ensure the ActivityResultLauncher is registered before calling launch(). But there is no method to check if ActivityResultLauncher is registered. How can I solve this and why this may happen? Also, it's not clear when to call unregister() method, any examples?

Comment: Some code would be useful here. How is your ActivityResultLauncher set up?

Answer (score 5):

Be aware to register your activityResultLauncher in `onCreate` method to prevent side-effect

```java
public class MyActiviy extends AppCompatActivity {
    .
    .
    .

    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> myLauncher;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //some stuff

        // Register your launcher here
        myLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK && result.getData() != null) {
                Intent data = result.getData();
            }
        });
      
        findViewById(R.id.myButton).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            // call `launch` after user click on button or something like that
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
            myLauncher.launch(intent);
        });
    }

}
```

Refere to Google doc :

> When using the ActivityResultRegistry APIs, it's strongly recommended
> to use the APIs that take a LifecycleOwner, as the LifecycleOwner
> automatically removes your registered launcher when the Lifecycle is
> destroyed. However, in cases where a LifecycleOwner is not available,
> each ActivityResultLauncher class allows you to manually call
> unregister() as an alternative.

Take a look at [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is what the linked documentation means - the quoted text is referring specifically to using the ActivityResultRegistry API and this is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: examples provided by Google show the registerForActivityResult done at property declaration though

Comment: That article found in the link, then proves to register launcher when the activity is initialized..
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#launch

Answer (score 5):

I have been experiencing the same error on all of my Apps on Playstore. After some experiments, I manage to figure out the solution. The problem was **"The Launcher gets called when the App leaves the activity"**.  To solve this error, I did only two thing.

**STEP # 1: Assigning the launcher as null on Activity Destroy.**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
     someActivityResultLauncher = null;
}
```

**STEP # 2: Adding a Null check before Launching it.**

```
 if(someActivityResultLauncher !=null)
      someActivityResultLauncher.launch(consentIntent);
```

Let me explain, My app had 2 activities. Phone number & verification activity. I had a broadcast that receives an OTP message and launched (). If the broadcast has received a message and the user is not on verification activity. The app would crash on Broadcast. Illegal state exception

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run (LoadedApk.java:972)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:743)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:150)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5621)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:794)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:684)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException:
  at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$2.launch (ActivityResultRegistry.java:168)
  at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher.launch (ActivityResultLauncher.java:47)
  at com.jazz.pakistani.drama.videos.deikho.Activities.Credentials.VerifyPassword$2.onReceive (VerifyPassword.java:289)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run (LoadedApk.java:962)
```

Comment: This worked for me... Especially this line if(someActivityResultLauncher !=null)

Comment: How did you reproduce the launcher getting called inside onDestroy?

Comment: I had an OTP screen. I typed the password manually and went to the next activity. When the password was received in sms the app crashed. So I added a null check inside OTP ACTIVITY to fix the issue.

Comment: So.... what do you do , if it is null indeed ?

Comment: if user back press than that activity is destroyed but launcher would be called and null pointer exception will occur. so to avoid that just add a null check

Answer (score 3):

This can also happen when your activity was destroyed and recreated due to configuration change such as when orientation was changed. You must re-initialize the `ActivityResultLauncher` inside `onCreate` or `onStart` before calling the `launch` again.