# You must ensure the ActivityResultLauncher is registered before calling launch()

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

In some android device, I'm getting this IllegalStateException in **ActivityResultLauncher**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to launch an unregistered ActivityResultLauncher with contract androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts$StartActivityForResult@3325833 and input Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN pkg=com.xyz.app cmp=com.xyz.app/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity (has extras) }. You must ensure the ActivityResultLauncher is registered before calling launch().
       at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$2.launch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:168)
       at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher.launch(ActivityResultLauncher.java:47)
       at com.xyz.app.ui.auth.login.LoginActivity.doAuth$lambda$22$lambda$20(LoginActivity.kt:318)
       at com.xyz.app.ui.auth.login.LoginActivity.$r8$lambda$zt4kZAeP81QjQuIivycpvJCWE4o()
       at com.xyz.app.ui.auth.login.LoginActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda7.onComplete(:4)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6977)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:528)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:910)
```

I have register launcher in onCreate() method.
When activity was destroyed and recreated due to configuration change such as when orientation was changed, I have re-initialize the ActivityResultLauncher inside onCreate before calling the launch again and also put a Null check before Launching it.

```
private lateinit var resultLauncherForGmailSignIn: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> myLauncher;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
         resultLauncherForGmailSignIn =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
                val intentData: Intent? = result.data
                intentData?.let {
                    loginViewModel.signInWithGmail(it)
                }
            }
      
        findViewById(R.id.myButton).setOnClickListener(v -> {
                    if (this::resultLauncherForGmailSignIn.isInitialized) {
                        resultLauncherForGmailSignIn.launch(signInIntent)
                    }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you showed is for `MyActivity` while the crash you posted is in `LoginActivity`. You seem to be looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have answered yourself. You are calling `register` in the second `onCreate` call. That is wrong.

You can register it as a variable inside Activity class, something like

```
class MyActiviy : AppCompatActivity() {

    val resultLauncherForGmailSignIn: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        ...
    }
```

This will ensure, the register is invoked only once at *creation*, but not for recreate.

Or you can check the `savedInstanceState` parameter, it will not be null in case of *recreate* scenario.

Comment: Previously I wrote code as you suggest, but I was getting same issue after I have changed as per this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70211364/attempting-to-launch-an-unregistered-activityresultlauncher

Comment: Well, my suggested code is comming from the structure used here:  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#launch and I am using it without any issue. Maybe try to describe in more details, the behaviour you are facing? Are you able to reproduce the exception? What are the steps - button clicks, screen gmail login shown, change of orientation etc.